# React Router different layouts for different Routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I use two different layouts in the application: for content (`MainLayout` with footer and borders) and empty (`BlankLayout` without footer and borders).

```js
export type LayoutProps = {
  children: ReactNode,
}
```

**MainLayout**

```js
const MainLayout: React.FC<LayoutProps> = ({ children = null }) => (
  <div className='main-layout'>
    <div className='main-layout__content'>{children}</div>
    <FooterComponent />
  </div>
);

export default MainLayout;
```

**BlankLayout**

```js
const BlankLayout: React.FC<LayoutProps> = ({ children = null }) => (
  <div className='editor-layout'>
    <div className='editor-layout__content'>{children}</div>
  </div>
);

export default BlankLayout;
```

And using them with React-Router v6 in the **index.tsx**

```js
    <BrowserRouter>
      <MainBarLayout>
        <BlankLayout>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/editor' element={<EditorPage />} />
            <Route path='/view/*' element={<ViewPage />} />
          </Routes>
        </BlankLayout>
        <MainLayout>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='*' element={<NotFoundPage />} />
            <Route path='/' element={<IndexPage />} />
          </Routes>
        </MainLayout>
      </MainBarLayout>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

The main issue that, for example path '/editor' renders both `EditorPage` and `NotFoundPage` with both layouts.

[image: Multiple render]

But I need only one layout with only one page on the screen at the same time.
If I had one layout I would do something like this:

```js
    <BrowserRouter>
      <MainBarLayout>
        <MainLayout>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='*' element={<NotFoundPage />} />
            <Route path='/' element={<IndexPage />} />
            <Route path='/editor' element={<EditorPage />} />
            <Route path='/view/*' element={<ViewPage />} />
          </Routes>
        </MainLayout>
      </MainBarLayout>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

And it will be really easy.
But I do not know what to do with several layouts for different paths.
So, Please help me :)